# split hex number by two and add /x before each

Tags: php

I am trying to below task, 
get length of string ---->  add some thing to it ----> change to hex ----> write result like

for example: dechex result is equal 01a3cd--> the output should look like /x01/xa3/xcd
but this can be n bytes

below is the sample code I wrote but I am stock how to do the last part

```
$message="1 1,1,1,0,0,2,0,1000,0,2,0,1,,,,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,,,,,2,,,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,,,0,\"\\x0d\\x0dtest1\",0,800,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,1,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,0,,,,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0 2,2,2,0,0,2,0,1000,0,2,0,1,,,,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,,,,,2,,,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,,,0,\"\\x0d\\x0dplu2\",0,100,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,1,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,0,,,,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,";
$b=(strlen($message));

echo dechex($b);
echo dechex($b+18);
str_split (dechex($b));
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with `str_split` there? `dechex` converts decimal to hexadecimal so for example `dechex(11)` will return **string** representation which is equal to `a`.

Comment: What would be the exact expected output for your test case?

Comment: You can avoid that line since it didnt work. Okay when i got the length i need to converted to hex and then write it like this /x00.
forex: dechex result is equal 1cd the output should look like /x01/xcd

Answer (score 0):

To simply output the two low bytes of the value in the format you need (assuming the value will fit in 2 bytes), you can use [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php);

```
echo sprintf('\\x%02x\\x%02x', $b/256, $b%256);

>> \x01\xcc
```

Comment: what happen if we have n byte do we make for loop